# Google API oAuth2.0 -- Consumer is not registered

Tags: api, oauth-2.0

I have oAuth 2.0 code that works with other services (such as LinkedIn and Facebook) but niot Google.

The code fails with 'Consumer is not registered'. It certainly is. That is if this error means what I think it means but I do have the following in https://code.google.com/apis/console.

1. a project,
2. and a valid CLIENT_ID entry

**Client ID:**   107***********4ek7fl.apps.googleusercontent.com

**Client secret:**   Q6KbA**********FRbL

**Redirect URIs:**   urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, htp://{localhost}

The failure occurs when the request is first sent to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

No page is displayed asking the user to authenticate, the Google server returns "Consumer is not registered" in the response body.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: Paulius Matulionis, I do not know whether Frank found the answer, but that is possible: please, look at my below

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I am using the scribe oauth java library, https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java. It's support of Google is only oauth 1.0, so I had to write my own class that extends org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi20 instead of org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a.

Comment: Great initiative. Did you make a pull request on scribe or did you publish your implementation somewhere? No need to reinvent the wheel if someone already build it!

Comment: lluft, basically, I made up your comment and found one answer after some hours, please, look at my answer above

Comment: Scribe-Java Supports 2.0 now

Answer (score 0):

basically here you are:

```
package org.scribe.builder.api;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException;
import org.scribe.extractors.AccessTokenExtractor;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthConfig;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthConstants;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest;
import org.scribe.model.Response;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verb;
import org.scribe.model.Verifier;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;
import org.scribe.utils.OAuthEncoder;
import org.scribe.utils.Preconditions;

/**
 * Google OAuth2.0
 * Released under the same license as scribe (MIT License)
 * @author houman001
 * This code borrows from and modifies changes made by @yincrash
 * @author yincrash
 *
 */
public class Google2Api extends DefaultApi20 {

    private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s";
    private static final String SCOPED_AUTHORIZE_URL = AUTHORIZE_URL + "&scope=%s";
    private static final String SUFFIX_OFFLINE = "&" + OAuthConstants.ACCESS_TYPE + "=" + OAuthConstants.ACCESS_TYPE_OFFLINE
            + "&" + OAuthConstants.APPROVAL_PROMPT + "=" + OAuthConstants.APPROVAL_PROMPT_FORCE;


    @Override
    public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
        return "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    }

    @Override
    public AccessTokenExtractor getAccessTokenExtractor() {
        return new AccessTokenExtractor() {

            public Token extract(String response) {
                Preconditions.checkEmptyString(response, "Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from an empty string");

                Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\"access_token\" : \"([^&\"]+)\"").matcher(response);
                if (matcher.find())
                {
                    String token = OAuthEncoder.decode(matcher.group(1));
                    String refreshToken = "";
                    Matcher refreshMatcher = Pattern.compile("\"refresh_token\" : \"([^&\"]+)\"").matcher(response);
                    if (refreshMatcher.find())
                        refreshToken = OAuthEncoder.decode(refreshMatcher.group(1));
                    Date expiry = null;
                    Matcher expiryMatcher = Pattern.compile("\"expires_in\" : ([^,&\"]+)").matcher(response);
                    if (expiryMatcher.find())
                    {
                        int lifeTime = Integer.parseInt(OAuthEncoder.decode(expiryMatcher.group(1)));
                        expiry = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + lifeTime * 1000);
                    }
                    Token result = new Token(token, refreshToken, expiry, response);
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new OAuthException("Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: '" + response + "'", null);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthorizationUrl(OAuthConfig config) {
        // Append scope if present
        if (config.hasScope()) {
            String format = config.isOffline() ? SCOPED_AUTHORIZE_URL + SUFFIX_OFFLINE : SCOPED_AUTHORIZE_URL;
            return String.format(format, config.getApiKey(),
                    OAuthEncoder.encode(config.getCallback()),
                    OAuthEncoder.encode(config.getScope()));
        } else {
            String format = config.isOffline() ? AUTHORIZE_URL + SUFFIX_OFFLINE : AUTHORIZE_URL;
            return String.format(format, config.getApiKey(),
                    OAuthEncoder.encode(config.getCallback()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Verb getAccessTokenVerb() {
        return Verb.POST;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuthService createService(OAuthConfig config) {
        return new GoogleOAuth2Service(this, config);
    }

    private static class GoogleOAuth2Service extends OAuth20ServiceImpl {

        private DefaultApi20 api;
        private OAuthConfig config;

        public GoogleOAuth2Service(DefaultApi20 api, OAuthConfig config) {
            super(api, config);
            this.api = api;
            this.config = config;
        }

        @Override
        public Token getAccessToken(Token requestToken, Verifier verifier) {
            OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(api.getAccessTokenVerb(), api.getAccessTokenEndpoint());
            switch (api.getAccessTokenVerb()) {
                case POST:
                    request.addBodyParameter(OAuthConstants.CLIENT_ID, config.getApiKey());
                    // API Secret is optional
                    if (config.getApiSecret() != null && config.getApiSecret().length() > 0)
                        request.addBodyParameter(OAuthConstants.CLIENT_SECRET, config.getApiSecret());
                    if (requestToken == null) {
                        request.addBodyParameter(OAuthConstants.CODE, verifier.getValue());
                        request.addBodyParameter(OAuthConstants.REDIRECT_URI, config.getCallback());
                        request.addBodyParameter(OAuthConstants.GRANT_TYPE, OAuthConstants.GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
                    } else {
                        request.addBodyParameter(OAuthConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN, requestToken.getSecret());
                        request.addBodyParameter(OAuthConstants.GRANT_TYPE, OAuthConstants.GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN);
                    }
                    break;
                case GET:
                default:
                    request.addQuerystringParameter(OAuthConstants.CLIENT_ID, config.getApiKey());
                    // API Secret is optional
                    if (config.getApiSecret() != null && config.getApiSecret().length() > 0)
                        request.addQuerystringParameter(OAuthConstants.CLIENT_SECRET, config.getApiSecret());
                    request.addQuerystringParameter(OAuthConstants.CODE, verifier.getValue());
                    request.addQuerystringParameter(OAuthConstants.REDIRECT_URI, config.getCallback());
                    if(config.hasScope()) request.addQuerystringParameter(OAuthConstants.SCOPE, config.getScope());
            }
            Response response = request.send();
            return api.getAccessTokenExtractor().extract(response.getBody());
        }
    }

}
```

from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codolutions/scribe-java/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/Google2Api.java